# Sending ClientHello Request from server

Tags: ssl, openssl

How one can do *ClientHello request* via OpenSSL? I have my server (and client) which is all set up and working, but a need arose to estabilish connection from within the server.

If I understand correctly `SSL_accept` will wait for *ClientHello* - which obviously don't solve my problem. `SSL_connect` is for client and will send *ClientHello* .

I assume a TCP connection has been made already and I just need to start TLS communication from my server.

Comment: You need to configure both the server and the client to reverse their SSL roles. Or else possibly use the STARTTLS protocol.

Comment: In this manner I won't get _ClientHello request_, am I right? If so, is there no solution to use this approach with OpenSSL? 

Your solution is of course easily implementable (though a little bit crude, at least in my opinion).

Comment: *"... but a need arose to estabilish connection from within the server"* - to where? Are you trying to connect back to a former client?

Comment: In some cases yes, though sometimes just to some external client. But now when I think about it - isn't _ClientHello request_ possible only when renegotiating?